Only allow numbers with set /p command in Windows batch
I'm trying to write a program that ask a number from the user, and once the number is selected it's written in a .txt file. My problem is, when I use set /p the user could enter letters or symbols too, but I don't want it to be allowed.
So if the user writes something with a letter and/or a symbol, it should say something like "Not valid, please only use numbers."
The only case where letters are allowed is if the user types "fin", which would end the program.
So my idea was to add a new line where the "rem" lines are (because that's what I tried but it didn't work), and it would check if %lot% only has numbers or not. Does someone have an idea of how to proceed?
@echo off

set filename=myfile.txt

:start
set /p lot=

if /i %lot% equ FIN (
    goto fin
)

rem set /a verif=%lot%
rem if %verif% neq 0 (
rem echo Not valid, please only use numbers.
rem goto start
rem )

echo %lot% >> %filename%
echo ok & echo.
goto start


:fin
sort /unique %filename% > Lots-Trieuse.txt
endlocal


I suggest looking on the answers of Safe number comparison in Windows batch file.

At the moment I have no win machine to test it ,but your approach with set /a is good but incomplete. As far as I remember set /a set the result to 0 if the string starts with something different than number, or if it starts with a number strips out everything after the last digit. So you can try with:
:start
setlocal enableDelayedExapnsion
set /p lot=

if /i "!lot!" equ "FIN" (
    goto fin
)


set /a verif=%lot%
if !verif! equ 0 if !verif! neq !lot! (
   rem is not a number
   echo Not valid, please only use numbers.
   goto start
)

if !verif! neq 0 if !verif! neq !lot! (
   rem starts with a digit but is not a number
   echo Not valid, please only use numbers.
   goto start
)
endlocal

Though have in mind that strings starting with 0x will be taken as hexadecimals and strings starting with 0 as octals and the result might be different than expected. You might need an additional step for removing leading zeroes.
Antoher approach is to use FINDSTR - this will work with bigger than 32bit numbers:
echo %lot% | findstr /r "^[0-9]*$" && (
   echo is a number
) || (
   echo is NOT a number
)

Or you can use exit /b and errorlevel - though it will remove leading zeroes and will assign the errorlevel to 0 if not a number is used:
cmd /c exit /b %lot%

if %errorlevel% equ 0 if %errorlevel% neq %lot% (
  echo NOT a number
)


I've used filenames that suit my system.
Always use a setlocal flavour to avoid environment clutter. Normally, a setlocal line should follow @echo off
Use set "var=value" for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign " or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier.
Changed label from start to begin because start is a batch keyword.
set lot to nothing before executing a userprompt version of set /p because if the user simply replies Enter then the value of lot remains unchanged.
Allow simply Enter to terminate as well as fin.
The gymnastics around notnumber is to prefix the lot value with a 9, then remove 0..9 from the resultant string. The 9 is added to guarantee that the string has a value when each of the digits is removed. If the string exists after every digit has been removed, then it is not a pure-numeric string...
Note that the append to file can precede the echo command. As you originally programmed it, there would be a trailing Space at the end of each line.
Note that the sort will produce output in ALPHABETICAL order, so 167 will sort before 3 because 1 is less than 3
Note that this code will allow leading 0. Caution when applying set /a since set /a would error if asked to convert the string 018 for instance since a leading 0 indicates that the string is to be interpreted as OCTAL, not DECIMAL.
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set "filename=u:\myfile.txt"

:begin
set "lot="
set /p "lot=lot: "
IF NOT DEFINED lot GOTO fin
if /i "%lot%" equ "FIN"goto fin

SET "notnumber=9%lot%"
FOR /l %%z IN (0,1,9) DO CALL SET "notnumber=%%notnumber:%%z=%%"

IF DEFINED notnumber echo %lot% not valid, please only use numbers.&GOTO begin
>>%filename% echo %lot%
echo %lot% ok & echo.
goto begin


:fin
sort /unique <%filename% >u:\Lots-Trieuse.txt

GOTO :EOF

